# Finding number of days until a certain date

Tags: javascript, datetime, node.js

I'm using Node.js and Moment in order to retrieve the days until the next 8th:

```
const getDaysTillSalary = (day) => {
    const today = moment();
    const currentDay = moment().format('D');
    let currentMonth = moment().format('M');
    let currentYear = moment().format('Y');
    const isCurrentDayGreater = parseInt(currentDay) > day;

    currentYear = isCurrentDayGreater && parseInt(currentMonth) === 12 ? moment().add(1, 'year').format('Y') : currentYear;
    currentMonth = isCurrentDayGreater ? moment().add(1, 'months').format('M') : currentMonth;

    const salaryDate = moment(`${day}-${currentMonth}-${currentYear}`, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

    return salaryDate.diff(today, 'days');
}

getDaysTillSalary(8);
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner and maybe efficient way to solve this problem, and will be glad to get some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const currentDay = moment().format('D');
```

You use `.format()` a lot, instead use Moment.js's [getters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) like [`.date()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/). This way you also don't have to use `parseInt()` since the getters return `number`'s.

---

What about this solution:

```
const getDaysTillSalary = (day) => {
  let date = moment();
  let days = 0;
  while(date.date() !== 8) {
    date = date.add(1, 'day');
    days++;
  }
  return days;
}
```

It creates a variable and stores the current Moment.js date in it. Then it repeatedly adds one day using `.add()` and counts up until `date.date()` (the day of the month) returns `8`. The `days` variable is then returned.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because you neither review the code nor explained what you did.

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm new to the Code Review community. I added some feedback and explained my solution.

Comment: Well done. Now I can undo the vote ;-)